Add unencrypted abscissa value
I would like to be able to add values ​​on the y-axis, which are not encrypted (for example: a)
When I want to add it, with my code, I don't see anything displayed:
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[    
            axis lines = center,
            xticklabels=none,
            yticklabels=none,
            xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
            xlabel = $x$,
            ylabel = {$y$},
            xmin=0,
            xmax=11,
            ymax=0.12,
            ymin=0
            ]
            \addplot [
            domain=0:10,
            samples=500, 
            color=red,
            ]
            {0.1-0.01*x};
            
            \node[left] at (0,0.1){a};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



what do you mean by encrypted here? tex does not encrypt anything, you are preventing values along the vertical axis with ytick=\empty, yticklabels=none if you remove them, the numbers are printed, is that what you mean?

You needs clip=false (see the pgfplots manual). But in your example, I would use
extra y ticks={0.1},
extra y tick label={a}

Example:
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines = center,
      xticklabels=none,
      yticklabels=none,
      xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
      xlabel = $x$,
      ylabel = {$y$},
      xmin=0,
      xmax=11,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=0.12,
      clip=false,
    ]
    \addplot [
      domain=0:10,
      samples=500,
      color=red,
    ]
    {0.1-0.01*x};

    \node[left] at (0,0.1){a};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
      axis lines = center,
      xticklabels=none,
      yticklabels=none,
      xtick=\empty,ytick=\empty,
      xlabel = $x$,
      ylabel = {$y$},
      xmin=0,
      xmax=11,
      ymin=0,
      ymax=0.12,
      extra y ticks={0.1},
      extra y tick label={a}
    ]
    \addplot [
      domain=0:10,
      samples=500,
      color=red,
    ]
    {0.1-0.01*x};

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


